# Pandas - Filtering value by columns throws error (ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1)

Tags: pandas

I have a Dataframe and I am trying to apply a filter as below:

```
df['flag'] = df[df['aging'].str.contains('5 days')]
```

But it returns the below error:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1
```

Given below is how my Dataframe looks like

```
id,date,current_date,aging
101,2018-12-01,2018-12-05,-5 days +15:34:11.000000000
102,2018-12-02,2018-12-05,-4 days +21:15:28.000000000
103,2018-12-03,2018-12-05,-3 days +15:43:06.000000000
104,2018-12-04,2018-12-05,-2 days +01:21:24.000000000
105,2018-12-05,2018-12-05,-1 days +01:21:14.000000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter your df without creating a new column :

```
print(df[df['aging'].str.contains('5 days')])
```

If you want to create a new column, you can do so :

```
df['Flag'] = df['aging'].str.contains('5 days')
```

The problem with your code is that you both filter and create a new column in the same time.