# Filter Pandas DataFrame Column Error: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I created a pandas DataFrame with some columns of Numpy arrays. I would like to filter one of the column and assign it to the new column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Signal' : signalarr, 'Signal RMS with Peaks' : RMS_Calculator(signalarr)} , columns=['Signal','Signal RMS with Peaks'])
df['Signal CMA with Peaks'] = df['Signal'].expanding(2).mean()
df.loc[[0], ['Signal CMA with Peaks']] = df['Signal'][0]
df['Peaks'] = random_peak

#print(df[df['Signal'] >= 10])
#df['Signal Without Peaks'] = df[df['Signal'] >= 10] # error: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1
df['Signal Without Peaks'] = df['Signal'] >= 10 # I need the values, not the boolean.
df
```

I read this post [Pandas - Filtering value by columns throws error (ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53815073/pandas-filtering-value-by-columns-throws-error-valueerror-wrong-number-of-it) and tried the solution, but am still getting the error.

With filtering like this `df['Signal Without Peaks'] = df[df['Signal'] >= 10]` , I didn't get the error before. Any ideas where I am wrong?
Thanks!

**Update:** I created the other dataframe before and with filtering the values, I got NaN values which is desired result for my application.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(signalarr, columns=['Signal'])
df['Signal Without Peaks'] = df[df['Signal'] <= 10]
```

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QTZP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, all the columns of a dataframe have the same length (which is thus also called the length of the dataframe). That's why you can't add a filtered (thus shorter) column as a new column to the original dataframe.

Instead, you may want to assign the filtered values to a new name, e.g.:

```py
df_without_peaks = df[df['Signal'] >= 10]
```

**Edit:** To fill in NaN values when the signal has a value less than 10, you can use [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```py
import numpy as np
df['Signal filtered'] = np.where(df['Signal'] >= 10, df['Signal'], np.nan)
```

Comment: Thanks, so maybe one way would be to fill the raw with NaN values when the signal has a value less than 10. I am not sure how.

Comment: Sure, that could be done. I've added one way to my answer.